# Updating R 3.5.3 to R 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates, repository

I have been trying to move from this version for a while, however all attempts have failed.
The steps I am following:

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base r-base-dev
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
```

output:

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/grass/grass-stable/ubuntu bionic Release     
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

after:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

output:

```
--recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: clave 51716619E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" sin cambios
gpg: Cantidad total procesada: 1
gpg:              sin cambios: 1
```

after:

```
sudo apt update
```

output:

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/grass/grass-stable/ubuntu bionic Release     
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

after:

```
sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

output:

```
r-recommended : Depende: r-cran-boot (>= 1.2.19) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-cluster (>= 1.9.6-2) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-foreign (>= 0.7-2) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-mgcv (>= 1.1.5) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-rpart (>= 3.1.20) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-survival (>= 2.13.2-1) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-mass pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-class pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-nnet pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-codetools pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-matrix pero no va a instalarse
```

Comment: Please show us the contents of your APT *sources.list*s - execute `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` and add its output to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1254106/edit). Also please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base r-base-core r-recommended` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to remove [problematic PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egrass/+archive/ubuntu/grass-stable) (it does no publish packages for 18.04 LTS - *bionic*) first with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:grass/grass-stable
```

and then update your package lists

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install new updates with their dependencies by

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

You have added R 3.5 repository (see *bionic-cran35* in its URL), instead of needed R 4.0 (*bionic-cran40*). You have to remove wrong repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
```

and then add correct one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/'
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

Comment: I update various python packages, but not R. After following their steps, I ran: "sudo apt-get install r-base-core". Again, I am in version 3.5.3

Comment: After "sudo apt upgrade r-base r-base-dev", I get:                                                                                      

r-base-dev is already in its latest version (3.5.3-1bionic).


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base: Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.3-1bionic) but will not install
E: Broken packages

Comment: See update above.

Comment: r-base: Depends: r-base-core (> = 4.0.2-1.1804.0) but 3.5.3-1bionic is going to be installed                            Recommends: r-base-html but will not install
 r-recommended: Depends: r-base-core (> = 4.0.2-1.1804.0) but 3.5.3-1bionic is going to be installed
                 Depends: r-cran-mass but will not install
                 Depends: r-cran-class but will not install
                 Depends: r-cran-nnet but will not install
                 Depends: r-cran-spatial but will not install
E: The problems could not be corrected, you have retained broken packages.