# Unable to install R 4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: updates, r

I followed [this post here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237102/problem-installing-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-18-04) to install R 4.0, however in the last step

```
sudo apt install r-base
```

I get the following error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.3-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
    Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did go down the rabbit hole as someone has mentioned in an answer about this issue and I am still unable to overcome this error.Thanks

Comment: You have to use official guide from CRAN - https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to install aptitude, which will try to resolve the conflict. See that answer to this question answering the [held broken packages issue.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)